# Скроллинг ListView WPF при обновлении ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, xaml, mvvm

Всем привет. Есть вот такой список, на котором отображаются сообщения мессенджера.

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Messages, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="2"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <uc:MessageView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при получении или отправке сообщения (т.е. при обновлении связанного с `ListView` коллекции сообщений) он скроллился в конец, не нарушая при этом концепцию MVVM? Коллекция сообщений представляет собой `ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое что пришло в голову это после добавления выбрать этот элемент и прокрутить до него скрол. Примерно так:
Заводим в VM свойство

```
public Message SelectedItem
{
тут по стандарту
}
```

В xaml

```
<ListView Selected="ListView_Selected" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

В xaml.cs

```
    private void ListView_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView lv = sender as ListView;

        if (lv.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            lv.ScrollIntoView(lv.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

После добавления нового сообщения

```
SelectedItem = newMessageItem
```

Как-то так.

Comment: А где тут MVVM?

Comment: Задача была не нарушать MVVM.

Comment: Основная цель MVVM - разделить все на слои (Model/View/ViewModel), где View слой не должен знать о ViewModel/Model, а Model не должен знать о View/ViewModel. То есть мы не можем скажем в VM написать `textBox1.Text...`. Теперь давайте уберем у вас из кода обработчик события `ListView_Selected`, запуститься ли приложение? Нет, потому что мы из View ссылаемся на него явно (тем самым нарушая MVVM). С другой стороны тут смотря какой проект... Некоторые проекты допускают использование Click или других событий, но это уже не полноценный MVVM подход (называется он Не строгий подход)!

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить ,что вы считаете  xaml.cs ViewModel'ю так-ли это? Для меня  xaml.cs ни какого отношения к ViewModel в реальном проекте не имеет.

Comment: Я вам говорю про сам XAML, он не каким образом в чистом (строгом) MVVM не должен ссылаться на код, только Binding. Будем считать, что у вас не строгий подход (который я не считаю за MVVM)...

Comment: Пусть будет так. Я бы с удовольствием посмотрел на строгую реализацию данного вопроса

Comment: @EGOIST, спасибо, с небольшими изменениями (у меня почему-то не сработало с событием Selected, но я заменил его на SelectedChanged) всё запустилось как надо. Правда, есть побочный эффект: выделенное сообщение))))

Comment: @EvgeniyZ к сожалению, WPF не на 100% сам по себе соответствует паттерну MVVM и иногда легче перестать есть кактус, чем продолжать упарываться.

Comment: 0x00x выделение можно сбросить SelectedItem = null

Comment: @EGOIST, ага, как раз так и сделал уже))