# Событие - Когда добавляется что либо в StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

Я прикрутил к `StackPanel` скролл, но он не так пока работает как мне хотелось бы.
Он стоит на месте, когда содержимого больше чем высота `StackPanel`.
Мне же хочется всегда видеть последний добавленный элемент в `StackPanel`.

Как я понял, мне нужно опускать скролл программно при добавлении элемента в `StackPanel`, как отловить это событие ? на [MSDN про StackPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) что то не нашёл.

**Короче говоря:** Как называется событие у `StackPanel`, когда я добавляю в него элемент ?

Comment: [Скроллинг ListView WPF при обновлении ItemsSource](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877713/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-listview-wpf-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-itemssource) Похожий вопрос

Comment: почему StackPanel, почему не ListBox? ListBox как раз реализует такую возможность

Comment: @Gardes потому что я пока достаточно плохо знаю WPF и хватаюсь пока за то, что уже ковырял.

Comment: @Vipz, выложите ваш код, что сделали, а там уже посоветую как исправить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Универсальный совет, изучающим WPF - почитайте и разберитесь как использовать [паттерн MVVM](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php) (необязательно по этой ссылке). Большая вероятность, что после освоения MVVM у вас разрешиться множество вопросов, касаемо WPF.

Что касается вашего вопроса: скорее всего, вы идете неверным путем, но, так как вводных данных мало, будем работать с тем, что есть.

---

`StackPanel` не имеет события изменения коллекции детей, поэтому мы не можем отследить когда был добавлен или удален элемент. Опять-таки, скорее всего, вам нужно использовать другой контрол, но в качестве альтернативы можно приспособить для этих целей событие [LayoutUpdated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). Это событие происходит, когда обновляется layout элемента.

Подписываемся на событие и пишем в обработчике логику прокрутки `ScrollViewer` к последнему элементу:

**Xaml:**

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="sv" Grid.Row="1">
     <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" />
</ScrollViewer>
<Button Click="AddToStackPanel">Add item to StackPanel</Button>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stackPanel.LayoutUpdated += OnLayoutUpdated;
    }

    private bool _needToScroll = true;
    private void OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_needToScroll)
        {
            sv.ScrollToEnd();
            _needToScroll = false;
        }
    }

    private void AddToStackPanel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = new TextBlock {Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt")};
        stackPanel.Children.Add(tb);
        _needToScroll = true;
    }
}
```

Поле `_needToScroll` отвечает за то, нужно ли прокручивать `ScrollViewer` к последнему элементу. Это нужно чтобы пользователь мог вручную использовать прокрутку (не забываем, что при прокрутке layout контрола также обновляется и если флаг не использовать, то контрол будет прокручен всегда к последнему элементу). Соответственно этот флаг нужно устанавливать при добавлении/удалении элементов.

---

Интуитивно кажется, что вам больше подошел бы `ListBox` или `ItemsControl` на которые уже можно навешать поведение прокрутки к последнему элементу. Или же унаследоваться от стандартных и сделать контрол со своим поведением.

**Xaml:**

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ScrollToLastItemBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
<Button Grid.Row="2" Command="{Binding AddCommand}">Add item to ListBox</Button>
```

**ScrollToLastItemBehavior:**

```
public class ScrollToLastItemBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var listBox = AssociatedObject;
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)listBox.Items).CollectionChanged += OnListBox_CollectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        var listBox = AssociatedObject;
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)listBox.Items).CollectionChanged -= OnListBox_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnListBox_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBox = AssociatedObject;
        if (listBox.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var lastItem = listBox.Items[listBox.Items.Count - 1];
            listBox.ScrollIntoView(lastItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Во VieModel ничего особенного нет:

```
public class MainVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainVm()
    {
        AddCommand = new RelayCommand(AddItem);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }

    private void AddItem()
    {
        Items.Add("Current time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
    }

    #region INPC

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INPC
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]