# Как использовать метод в ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть приложение, в котором я хочу реализовать MVVM. В файле MainWindow.Xaml необходимо реализовать карусель, в которой находятся изображения. Все, что пока есть:

```
<Button x:Name="MoveImagesBack" Click="MoveImagesBack_Click" Style="{StaticResource MoveImagesButton}" Content="&lt;"/>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GamesImages}" x:Name="LoopPhotoCarousel" Margin="0 10" Grid.Column="1"
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
      BorderThickness="0"
     >
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>

<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Button Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource MoveImagesButton}" Content="&gt;"></Button>
```

В файле MainWindowViewModel.cs код:

```
ObservableCollection<string> gamesImages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> GamesImages
{
    get
    {
        if (gamesImages.Count <= 0)
        {
            gamesImages.Add(@"Images/Games/1.jpg");
            gamesImages.Add(@"Images/Games/2.jpg");
            gamesImages.Add(@"Images/Games/3.jpg");
            gamesImages.Add(@"Images/Games/4.jpg");
            gamesImages.Add(@"Images/Games/5.jpg");
            gamesImages.Add(@"Images/Games/6.jpg");
        }
        return gamesImages;
    }
}
```

В MainWindow.Xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(this);

    }
}
```

Так вот: во первых, у меня нигде не получается обратиться к списку LoopPhotoCarousel, для того чтобы попытаться реализовать метод клика на кнопку. Кроме того, я бы хотел, чтобы этот метод находился в файле MainWindowViewModel.cs. Сейчас возникает ошибка CS 1061, если он находится не в файле MainWindow.

1) Что прописать в конструкторе MainWindow, чтобы я мог нормально прописать метод в ViewModel?
2) Почему не видит имя списка?
3) Подсказка по реализации кнопок тоже не помешала бы. Я пока что нашел метод ScrollIntoView, но не уверен, что это то, что нужно.

Карусель такая: [1]: https://pp.userapi.com/c852232/v852232456/2162e/0k-F9DS8bj4.jpg

Comment: 1) `new MainWindowViewModel(this);` вьюмодель не должна ничего знать о вашем окне

Comment: 2) `чтобы попытаться реализовать метод клика на кнопку` это делается командой - изучите, как писать команды во вьюмодели и как биндить их к кнопкам

Comment: @tym32167 Как то смотрел пару видео от одного весьма хорошего парня, тот писал с нуля на WPF свой клиент чата. В проекте полностью переделывалось окно и для этого окна он создавал свою VM. В эту VM он как раз и передавал MainWindow. Сама же VM реализовывала всю логику окна (его размер, заголовок, кнопки, ресайз и куча другого). Я сначала подумал, что это временно, но он до сих пор использует это коде. Собственно то самое [видео](https://youtu.be/TDOxHx-AMqQ?list=PLrW43fNmjaQVYF4zgsD0oL9Iv6u23PI6M&t=1542) (в описании ссылка на GitHub). Собственно кто прав и как быть? Или здесь как с Click?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот оттуда я собственно это и взял. Смотрел ещё видосы какого то MVP Майкрософта, там с помощью autofac каким то образом все это работало. Но объяснения особого не было, поэтому я и не понял. И щас не до конца понимаю, как все это реализовать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сорри, слишком долгий видос, нет столько времени смотреть - но у меня есть проект с чатом и есть проект с кастомным окном и везде я обошелся без прокидывания окна во VM. Но если говорить в общем случае, то в программировании нет универсальных приемов, всегда надо соблюдать баланс и чем то жертвовать. Я уверен, если бы тот парень делал по уму, то видос был бы не на 2 часа, а на 20 минимум. Потому я его не виню - он проект сделал? Проект работает? Если да, то ок, хоть и с тех долгами. Но новичков прежде чем такому учить, надо предупреждать, что хорошо, а что плохо

Comment: @tym32167 Да дело то в том, что там не особо то для новичков и видно, что парень с "мозгами". Там дальше уйма всего у него полезного и я бы не сказал что базового... Проект он до сих пор делает, а это уже как ~1.5 года и до сих пор смотрю в коде у него [DataContext = new WindowViewModel(this)](https://github.com/angelsix/fasetto-word/blob/develop/Source/Fasetto.Word/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L28). У меня просто после [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/877756/220553) ответа начали прокрадываться сомнения по этому поводу, ведь и вправду, иногда проще передать элемент, чем городить сотни строк кода.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я же говорю, все дело в балансе. Если вы знаете что вы делаете и для чего и осознаете последствия, то вы можете делать так, как считаете нужным. Я вот 4 года пилю проект и вообще не грушаюсь [вот таким](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.ChatModule/Boxes/ColoredItemsControl.xaml.cs#L50), но это проект чисто для меня, на работе, когда нет спешки, то за подобное я по рукам могу настучать, так как там совсем другие требования к ПО, чем в пет проекте.

Comment: @tym32167 а как правильно? То есть у меня вообще не должно быть вьюмодельки MainWidowViewModel? Получается логику главного окна писать в MainWindow.Xaml.cs, а ui собственно в MainWindow.Xaml?

Comment: По определению паттерна у вас должны быть View (ваше окно), ViewModel - связущий модель и представление класс и Model